# Where is my latest build for my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, xcode4.2

This seems very strange, I recently upgraded to Xcode 4.2 and I'm about to release an updated version of my app. When I go to the Build folder non of the builds seem to have changed and they are all dated from before I updated to Xcode 4.2

My code has todays date but I cannot see where the lates builds are. Does Xcode 4.2 store the builds in a different place or am I missing a setting in Xcode?

Comment: Window -> Organizer, then Archives tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the "Log Navigator" icon (speech bubble) in the left pane, and select the log entry for your build.

The log will contain the full path to your build. Often it's something like:

```
/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cmxgycqjtykiurgecgrmvvavwwjq
/Build/Products/Debug/App.app/Contents/MacOS/App
```

If you are doing a production build, I recommend using the "Archive" feature, which will do a clean build with all the right compiler optimisations, and then present you with the build in the organiser window.

You can then click "share" to save the app in whatever format you prefer (pkg, app, ipa, etc). In the case of an iOS app, this will also offer to embed the provisioning profile in the app, which is nice for ad-hoc deployment.

Comment: Found it! Many thanks, it is still building as Debug though How do I change it to Release? It used to be an option in the toolbar but that has gone!

Comment: If you edit the "scheme" with the popup button in the toolbar to the right of the run/stop buttons, you can set which build operations will use debug, and which will use release. The "archive" operation is pre-configured to do a Release build, and this is what you should be using to create them.